# Ubuntu / GRUB reboot loop

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-12.04, grub

I had to shutdown a server due to a power outage... The machine's been working just fine, an Ubuntu 12.04 box. Now when I boot back up, I get the GRUB 1.99 boot menu with several options, all of which result in a blinking cursor for ~15 seconds, then reboots. There's no sign that anything's wrong, and I'm not familiar enough with the common troubleshooting steps to take to identify the issue. I suspect it's some sort of GRUB update problem (an update to GRUB may have been installed, and pending a reboot, which I just did). For further info, this is the GRUB boot config for the standard boot option:

```
set params 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-32-generic'

recordfail
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root LONGUUID
linux /vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic root=/dev/mapper/k2-root ro quiet $vt_handoff
initrd /initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic
```

Any ideas on what I can try would be great help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem!

Turned out somehow during a Grub update (or a previous partitioning of the disk) changed the default root partition in Grub to use `hd0,msdos`, which isn't actually correct. We found out on the Grub console that the root partition is merely `1`, so changing that fixed the issue.